# What is the intuition behind the regressive product and its axioms?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, clifford-algebras, geometric-algebras

I'm self-studying Grassmann algebra and I find it hard to visualize the regressive product, specifically the magnitude and orientation of the outcome.

My main soure is John Brown's [Grassman Algebra](https://books.google.hu/books/about/Grassmann_Algebra_Volume_1_Foundations.html?id=IuYIAwAAQBAJ&redir_esc=y) which introduces the following axiom with little explanation as to why this should be the case:
$$ (A \wedge C)\vee (B\wedge C)=(A\wedge B\wedge C)\vee C \tag{1}\label{1} $$

Now later in the book the author introduces another axiom which captures the dual nature of this product but unfortunatelly requires the space to have a metric:
$$ \overline{A \vee B} = \overline{A} \wedge \overline{B} \tag{2}\label{2} $$

This could also be the definition or we could also define it using the interior product...

My questions are:

1. Is there an intuitive and/or geometric justification for $\eqref{1}$?
2. How could I prove that in fact $\eqref{1}$ and $\eqref{2}$ are eqvivalent (as a definition of the regressive product)?

Comment: Can you define the bar notation? I have a vague idea of what it is, but your specific definition would be helpful.

Comment: (1) is false. Take $C = 1$ but $A\wedge B$ not a (nonzero) pseudoscalar; then $$(A \wedge 1)\vee(B\wedge 1) = A\vee B$$ but $$(A\wedge B\wedge1)\vee 1 = 0$$ because $X\vee 1 = 0$ whenever $X$ is not a pseudoscalar. (This is dual to the statement $X \wedge I = 0$ whenever $X$ is not a (nonzero) scalar and $I$ is a pseudoscalar).

Comment: The complement of a simple element $A$ is defined as: $A \wedge \overline{A} = |A|^2 I$, where $I$ is the unit pseudoscalar.

Comment: Yes, you are right. In the case you presented the regressive product is $0$, because $A$ and $B$ dont span the whole n dimensional space. That is their complements have similar factors, thus making the complements' exterior product $0$. The formula is really only interesting when $A \wedge B \wedge C$ is a nonzero pseudoscalar. But thank you, I really appriciate your comment.

Comment: If $A\wedge B\wedge C$ is a pseudoscalar then $(A\wedge B\wedge C)\vee C = |A\wedge B\wedge C|C$ or something similar. Then (1) is quite boring since all it's saying is $$(X\oplus Z)\cap(Y\oplus Z) = Z$$ for linearly independent subspaces $X, Y, Z$; or in other words "the intersection of two subspaces is the subspace which is their intersection".

Comment: Your $\bar A$ is not well defined. Consider 3D with standard basis $e_1, e_2, e_3$ and $I = e_1\wedge e_2\wedge e_3$. Then $e_1\wedge(e_2\wedge e_3) = I$ so supposedly $\bar A = e_2\wedge e_3$. But $e_1\wedge[(e_2+e_1)\wedge e_3] = I$ and $e_2\wedge e_3 \ne (e_2+e_1)\wedge e_3$.

Comment: But then why isn't it defined as: $ (A \wedge C) \vee (B \wedge C) = C$? What is the justification for that extra term? It seems rather arbitrary. About the complement, I'm sorry, should have written $ A \wedge \overline{A} = I $ such that $ |A| = |\overline{A}| $

Comment: The regressive product is linear, so $A$ and $B$ need to be in the RHS somehow. The exact scale factor doesn't matter though since simple multivectors represent subspaces up to a scalar multiple. I would never try to take (1) as a definition of the regressive product, and indeed it fails as one as demonstrated in my second comment.

Comment: A proper definition of the regressive product without a metric requires the *Poincare isomorphism* and the dual $V^*$ of our vector space $V$. There are two approaches, one using interior products and one using "complements". For the latter, we pick a pseudoscalar $I$ and get a bilinear form $$\langle A,B\rangle I:=\langle A\wedge B\rangle_n.$$ The RHS is the grade $n=\dim V$ projection. This gives a linear isomorphism $P:\bigwedge V\cong(\bigwedge V)^*\cong\bigwedge V^*$ which takes $\bigwedge^kV$ to $\bigwedge^{n-k}V^*$. The regressive product is then $$A\vee B:=P^{-1}(P(A)\wedge P(B)).$$